# Get entity from dataframe and save in other column

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I am make DataFrame with 2 columns:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Text1 | Text1 |
| Text2 | Text2 |
| Text3 | Text3 |

And I need to make another column with entity from column 1 and second with entity from column 2.
For example:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Entity 1 | Entity2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple is big corpotarion | United Kingdom, island country located off the northwestern coast of mainland Europe. | ORGname | GPE |
| There are 12 full moons in 2022, and two of them qualify as supermoons. | Google has begun investigating and testing solutions. | Date | ORG |
| London | which was released in 2015, if that gives some perspective | placeName | Date |

How can I do this using Python [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities) library?

Comment: 1. Nothing about this is spaCy specific? Adding columns isn't special because of spaCy. 2. You can't guarantee that there will only be one named entity per sentence.

Comment: So if sentence have more than one entity it can be added to column with comma.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my problem is lambda:

```
df['Entity1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).ents))
```

This code will add next column with entity from column 1 text.